# Effective way to convert SVG <path d=""></path> to DXF LWPOLYLINE (or suggest other entry)

Tags: node.js, svg, dxf

We need to insert a lot of SVG images into DXF file. We use NodeJS and self-written library for creating DXF files. The problem is that the DXF file is very big - 32 Mb with only one image. There are very long lines in source SVG file like this: '<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width=".5" d="M451.07 249.17L451 249.35M451 249.35L450.82 249.42M450.82 249.42L450.65 249.35M450.65 249.35L450.57 249.17M450.57 249.17L450.65 249M450.65 249L450.82 248.92M450.82 248.92L451 249M451 249L451.07 249.17M450.61 224.83L450.53 225M450.53 225L450.36 225.08M450.36 225.08L450.18 225M450.18 225L450.11 224.83M450.11 224.83L450.18 224.65M450.18 224.65L450.36 224.58M450.36 224.58L450.53 224.65M450.53 224.65L450.61 2...' and as a result our code creates a lot of LWPOLYLINE entries within DXF file.

It seems the SVG format is much more compact than DXF. Is there any way to reduce the size of DXF file perhaps by using other DXF entity than LWPOLYLINE? Or perhaps there is any other solution.

Thank you.

Comment: From seeing only the small excerpt of that path, and trying to render it, there is one thing I can say: This not a a sensible way to draw a vector grafic. The result looks like two small asterixes, but the way they are constructed could also mean someone wanted to draw two small circles, but an import to SVG botched the intent. I think there is no way around analysing what these `<path>` elements are trying to draw, and to work out if there are automatic ways to re-draw them in a simpler (more compact) way preserving their grafical semantics.

Comment: DXF does not support quaradic nor cubic Bézeir curvs, so if your path contains such curves, they have to be flattened, there is no way around that.

Comment: LWPOLYLINE is the most compact entity to draw polylines.

Comment: <path>'s in our files have only M, L, and A entries and render successfully. size is the only problem.

Comment: It is not clear what is your need, the title says you need to convert an SVG path to a DXF lwpolyline, but at the end of the question it seems that your real concern is about the size of the DXF. I don't think you can do much about the size of the resulting DXF, but the conversion is possible, of course.